# Creating new Outlook mail item with javascript and vbscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript, outlook

I have a custom HTML page with fields and a button to fill out and generate a new Outlook mail item. I need the body to be formatted with HTML so I'm using VBScript to create a new mail item.

```
<script>
function generateEmail() {
  var emailTo = $("#toField").val();
  var emailCC = $("#CC").val();
  var emailSubject = $("#subject").val();
  var reason = $('#otherRadioBtn').is(':checked')?$("#otherFreeTextField").val():$(".reason:checked").val();
  var emailBody = "<html><body><p><b>Issue:</b> " + $("#issue").val() + "<p><b>Customer Contact Information:</b> " + $("#contactInformation").val() + "<p><b>Requested Action:</b> " + $(".requestedAction:checked").val() + "<p><b>Reason:</b> " + reason + "<p><b>Workaround Available?</b> " + $(".workaround:checked").val() + "</body></html>";
  sendEmail()
};
</script>

<script type="text/vbscript">
  Sub sendEmail()
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
      objMail.display
      objMail.to = emailTo
      objMail.cc = emailCC
      objMail.subject = emailSubject
      objMail.htmlbody = emailBody
  End Sub
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Generate email" onclick="generateEmail()">
```

Whenever I hit the "generate email" button, I receive the error "'sendEmail' is undefined." I'm not sure why. What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: Where do you run the code? What web browser did you use?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev This is for my team in my organization, we all use IE and Outlook. This is all in an HTML file.

Comment: You need to enable the `Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe for scripting` option in the IE Options dialog.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev That is already enabled.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the code? Did you try to debug?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No, literally all it says is "sendEmail is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

The code may work only in Internet Explorer on a system with Outlook installed.

You need to change the settings of Internet explorer for this to work:

a)      Go to `Tools` menu in the internet explorer.

b)      Go to `Options`.

c)       Click `Custom Level` Button.

d)      Select the option `Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe for scripting` to `Prompt` or `Enable`.

You may find more information and a sample code in the [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rajnishkaushik/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007/) article.